# Need to optimize the MySQL query to use that one in Solr

Tags: mysql, optimization, solr

I need to optimize the following query. Right now, it takes 1 min 54 sec on to the server and I need to optimize this query to run less than a min means less than 60 sec.

```
SELECT 
      a.article_id, 
      a.provider_id, 
      a.status, 
      a.modified_at, 
      a.published_at, 
      a.title, 
      a.summary, 
      a.image, 
      GROUP_CONCAT(af.feed_id SEPARATOR ', ') AS feed_id_list 
   FROM 
      article a 
         INNER JOIN  article_feed af
            ON af.article_id = a.article_id 
   GROUP BY 
      a.article_id 
   ORDER BY
      NULL
```

How can I optimize this query so that it can execute in less than 60 sec?

Here Is the explain of the query.

```
id|Select_type|table|type  |Possible_keys|key    |Key_len|ref               |rows   |extra
1 |Simple     |  af |index |primary      |primary|7      |NULL              |1791305|Using index;usingtemporary
1 |simple     | a   |Eq_ref|primary      |primary|4      |Feed.af.article_id|   1   |   -
```

Comment: 1.54 seconds is less than 60 seconds. Congrats, you did that!

Comment: ok, Am I missing something? 1.54 seconds on a server IS less than 60 seconds...  Does the article_feed table have an index on article_id?  How many articles (roughly), and how many article feeds...

Comment: What does `EXPLAIN SELECT ...` say?

Comment: For optimization, we need query (check), schema, and EXPLAIN, and it's still kind of trial and error since we don't have data.

Comment: I have update and also attached the explain of the query.
zerkms: it's not 1.54 sec it means 1 min 54 sec.

Answer (score 0):

You select **everything** from the table, join another table and group the result set.

Obviously it takes some time to read 1.7M rows.

So the only advice could be - buy a faster storage (ie SSD), because you anyway need to read **all** the data to return the result

Comment: Thanks Zerkms for your reply. we are using NetApp storage solution. and it's tense to impossible to change that one and not even worth option. I am looking for another solution.